# unable to deploy to a windows mobile device

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I've written a simple 'hello world' app which runs fine in an emulator, but when I attempt to deploy it to a device it crashes in generated code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.mainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu();
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(54, 153);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 53);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
    this.AutoScroll = true;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 268);
    this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
    this.Menu = this.mainMenu1; // **<-- RIGHT HERE, the error is: "ObjectDisposed Exception was unhandled"**
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

If I uncomment that line and run it in an emulator it still works fine, if I deploy it to the device I get a runtime error with a log that isn't of much help.

I've set the compiler to send the latest .net ce to the device, it's a Windows mobile 6.1 Motorola MC5590.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the device [off and on again](http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Roy-with-his-meh--t-shirt-the-it-crowd-242640_1024_576.jpg) solved the problem, whatever it was.